# INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND data type: find values greater than 1 minute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, timestamp, compare

time_created and time_ended are VARCHAR fields.

SQL statement

```
SELECT time_created,
   time_ended,
   TO_TIMESTAMP (time_ended, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9')
   - TO_TIMESTAMP (time_created, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9')
  FROM trans
```

output

```
2012/10/28-18:46:13.855 2012/10/28-18:47:43.357 +00 00:01:29.502000
2012/10/20-22:40:10.363 2012/10/20-22:40:35.265 +00 00:00:24.902000
2012/10/20-22:40:08.951 2012/10/20-22:40:24.717 +00 00:00:15.766000
2012/10/20-22:40:09.454 2012/10/20-22:40:28.217 +00 00:00:18.763000
2012/10/20-22:40:09.912 2012/10/20-22:40:31.767 +00 00:00:21.855000
2012/10/22-10:11:29.360 2012/10/22-10:14:08.692 +00 00:02:39.332000
2012/10/22-10:11:08.335 2012/10/22-10:11:43.781 +00 00:00:35.446000
2012/10/20-22:40:07.900 2012/10/20-22:40:17.508 +00 00:00:09.608000
2012/10/20-22:40:08.469 2012/10/20-22:40:21.144 +00 00:00:12.675000
2012/10/22-11:00:42.355 2012/10/22-11:01:41.706 +00 00:00:59.351000
2012/10/22-10:11:09.268 2012/10/22-10:11:54.185 +00 00:00:44.917000
2012/10/22-10:11:13.072 2012/10/22-10:12:21.365 +00 00:01:08.293000
```

I wish where clause which shows me only records greater than 1 minute.

I use Oracle Database 10g on Sun Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you alias the difference column, you can wrap this in an outer select and just add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT time_created,
        time_ended,
        TO_TIMESTAMP (time_ended, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9')
            - TO_TIMESTAMP (time_created, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9') AS diff
    FROM trans
)
WHERE diff > INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```

With dummy data to match your output, populated in a CTE:

```
with trans as (
select '2012/10/28-18:46:13.855' time_created,
    '2012/10/28-18:47:43.357' time_ended from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:10.363', '2012/10/20-22:40:35.265' from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:08.951', '2012/10/20-22:40:24.717' from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:09.454', '2012/10/20-22:40:28.217' from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:09.912', '2012/10/20-22:40:31.767' from dual
union all select '2012/10/22-10:11:29.360', '2012/10/22-10:14:08.692' from dual
union all select '2012/10/22-10:11:08.335', '2012/10/22-10:11:43.781' from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:07.900', '2012/10/20-22:40:17.508' from dual
union all select '2012/10/20-22:40:08.469', '2012/10/20-22:40:21.144' from dual
union all select '2012/10/22-11:00:42.355', '2012/10/22-11:01:41.706' from dual
union all select '2012/10/22-10:11:09.268', '2012/10/22-10:11:54.185' from dual
union all select '2012/10/22-10:11:13.072', '2012/10/22-10:12:21.365' from dual
)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT time_created,
        time_ended,
        TO_TIMESTAMP (time_ended, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9')
            - TO_TIMESTAMP (time_created, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS:FF9') AS diff
    FROM trans
)
WHERE diff > INTERVAL '1' MINUTE

TIME_CREATED            TIME_ENDED              DIFF
----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------
2012/10/28-18:46:13.855 2012/10/28-18:47:43.357 +000000000 00:01:29.502000000
2012/10/22-10:11:29.360 2012/10/22-10:14:08.692 +000000000 00:02:39.332000000
2012/10/22-10:11:13.072 2012/10/22-10:12:21.365 +000000000 00:01:08.293000000

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. The only litte thing: at me the alias "diff" doesn't work in where clause. I need to put full command. **Exactly what I was looking for.**

Comment: @fyodor78 - a column alias won't work in the `where` clause at the same level it's defined; that's why I put the outer `select`, which *can* use the `diff` value from the inner (original) query. But it's just as good to write it all out at one level - I just thought this would be a bit clearer. (Also... don't store timestamps (or anything else) in `varchar2` fields, always use the right data type. Doesn't make a lot of difference here but not a good habit).